# Keylogger transmitting photos when copy paste

Tags: keyloggers

In my work, I do a lot copy paste graphs or photos between folders. Can keyloggers steal these graphs or photos by transmitting them?
Thanks.

Comment: A pure keylogger couldn't, but it would be possible to have a keylogger than detected copy/paste key combinations and sent the clipboard contents to a third party, or to write software to hook into the OS clipboard directly.

Comment: This would require a lot of traffic (photos are bigger then text [Citation Needed]). As the purpose of keyloggers is to stay hidden they are unlikely to things that would give them away, like this.

Answer (score 11):

From [10 Immutable Laws of Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722487.aspx)...

> **Law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not your computer anymore**

If a "keylogger" of any form is running on your computer, then this has probably already happened. The bad guy's program can pretty well do anything he's designed it to do.

If this has happened to you, it's time to call Game Over and nuke from orbit.

Answer (score 2):

A "pure" keylogger would record <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> at best, which is not particularly useful in this context. **But** pure keyloggers are usually just one sub-component of malwares which have many more features. So if you have malware on your machine, it can potentially do whatever it wants, including taking screenshots at any time and sending any files to a remote machine.